# VS2012 says "The configProtectionProvider attribute is not allowed" for ConnectionStrings section

Tags: c#, connection-string

Even though [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows the attribute right in the  tag, when I try to code it, I get the dreaded blue squiggly under the line, and the hover message is as I put in the title of this question.  What do I need to do in order to activate this feature, since Microsoft's pages clearly show it being done this way.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1771774.aspx

Comment: I removed the attribute, did the encryption with Aspnet_regiis.exe, which added it back, and everything seems to work fine, even though VS still complains about the attribute.

Answer (score 7):

I think configProtectionProvider attribute is only supported in .NET 2.0. You can use it by adding the following

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0"
```

to your Configuration node like this:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
```